# sencha extjs npm build on Heroku requires JRE

Tags: node.js, heroku, extjs

Trying to get my sencha ExtJS app to compile on heroku. It is an npm app but requires JRE to compile. How do I make JRE available on heroku? my thinking is a build pack but have no idea how to find one that suits my needs or make one.

I appreciate any help that does not include the idea of "don't use extjs".   ;)

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 16.x...
       Downloading and installing node 16.17.1...
       Using default npm version: 8.15.0
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       npm ERR! code 126
       npm ERR! path /tmp/build_6f27fe6d/node_modules/@sencha/cmd
       npm ERR! command failed
       npm ERR! command sh /tmp/install-bad0c5cf.sh
       npm ERR! i [ext]: platform-install: @sencha/cmd v7.6.0 installed
       npm ERR! A JRE is required to download and run Sencha Cmd in linux.
       
       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.ImKdt/_logs/2022-10-09T17_30_24_436Z-debug-0.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       Some possible problems:
       
       - Node version not specified in package.json
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```